# Why again and again tomcat Error occurred during initialization of VM

Tags: linux

I took a virtual private server from godaddy and this the version of linux i am using

```
CentOS release 6.7 (Final)
```

The issue i am facing is that when i m trying to start tomcat i am seeing the below error

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

So i googled it and created a file named named setenv.sh with under

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Xms512m"
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Xmx8192m"
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"
```

/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.65/bin/

but still i am facing the same error

and this is the output of my ulimit -a

```
root@s97-74-229-181 [/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.65/bin]# ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 1029717
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 10240
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 1029717
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

could you please tellme how to resolve this issue

```
output of my ulimit commands

ulimit -S -u
1029717


ulimit -H -u
1029717
```

**My Memory info**

```
root@s97-74-229-181 [/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.65/bin]# cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:        1048576 kB
MemFree:          497752 kB
Cached:           212220 kB
Buffers:               0 kB
Active:           112208 kB
Inactive:         407020 kB
Active(anon):      27520 kB
Inactive(anon):   284700 kB
Active(file):      84688 kB
Inactive(file):   122320 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:             0 kB
SwapFree:              0 kB
Dirty:                 4 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:        312220 kB
Shmem:              5212 kB
Slab:              31540 kB
SReclaimable:      16532 kB
SUnreclaim:        15008 kB
```

Answer (score 0):

Tell your host to configure privvmpages and vmguarpages much higher. There's no need for them to be the same as physical memory as that impacts the way linux memory works

You might be able to work around the problem temporarily by dropping your file cache echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches but that's only temporary.

You can limit the chunk of memory java tries to allocate at run time with a minimum Xms or while running with maximum Xmx. Running java with these options on my machine:

java -Xms10M -Xmx10M
reduces the total virtual size to 140MB or so with only a 10MB contiguous chunk for the java heap allocated.

Comment: When i ran the command it gave me 
cache echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
-bash: /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches: Permission denied

Comment: Do you know what you Java heap size is set for?

Comment: for setting the heap size ..(needed for JVM to run)

Comment: Run the JVM with -XX:MaxHeapSize=512m (or any big number) (or -Xmx512m for short)

Comment: i set it this way inside tomcat's setenv.sh
export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -server -Xms512m -Xmx512m but still the same error

Comment: Have you opened a ticket with godaddy support? This make be a baked in setting on they're end